# String trimming

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, substr

I have a string as `x='SP0045.32489455187.206205008796197'` and i need the string as `'SP0045.32489455187'` . What could be my sql query .

Comment: What is the rule - discard everything from the second "."?

Comment: Perhaps if you make your question clearer these nice people will remove their downvotes!

Comment: use SUBSTRING() it returns a specified number of characters from a particular position of a given string.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your rule is `discard everything after and including the second "."` then:

```
substr(x, 1, instr(x,'.',1,2)-1)
```

See documentation of [instr](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm) and [substr](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm) for details.